# pointer-events on a href Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I saw ways to use pointer-events on SVG in Internet Explorer, but for a project I need to alter the a href's (pointer-events: none). How am I going to do this?

(I cannot alter the code, can only add CSS)

Thanks! :)

Comment: If you look at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), you'll see that `ponter-events` **does not work on `links` in IE11**.

Comment: Not even a tiny small piece of js code ?

Comment: I can add JS but only if I don't alter the a href's (I can't place an ID/Class on it or whatever)

Comment: please provide the html and precise which links you want to disable

Comment: <div id="custom-nav-inner">
                <ul>
 <li><a href="/">Home</a></li><span>|</span>
 <li><a href="/the-device">The Device</a></li><span>|</span>
 <li><a href="/musthaves.html">Musthaves</a></li><span>|</span>
</ul>    </div>

(The pointer-events: none is on the a)

Comment: Are you trying to disable **all** links in this menu or just some of them?

Comment: By the way...you cannot have `span`s as children of a `ul`.

Comment: Yes Paulie, all the links. (Also, I cannot edit anything in the menu itself, so I'll pass your message on. Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to disable **all** the links in this menu then there is a CSS option involving an `::after` pseudo-element on the `li` which overlays the anchor link.

The optimal solution would be javascript.

If you want to target a specific list item / anchor combo you could use the same technique using nth-child.

```
 li:nth-child (insert your number here)
```

Based on the structure given.

```css
#custom-nav-inner {
    display: inline-block;
}
#custom-nav-inner li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative; /* positioning context */
}
#custom-nav-inner li a {
    display: block;
    background: #bada55;
    padding:0.25rem 1rem;
}

#custom-nav-inner li a:hover {
    background: #f06d06;
}
#custom-nav-inner li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div id="custom-nav-inner">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="/the-device">The Device</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="/musthaves.html">Musthaves</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up pasting some jQuery in:


$(function(){
$('#custom-nav a, .footer-container a, .footer-end a').click(function() { return false; });
});

(the a that I wanted to edit)

Though Paulie_D his way worked swell too :)